# In Scala, are semicolons necessary in some situations?

Tags: scala

I'm studying Scala and trying to use it in my recent projects. And problems come. Here's one of my problem about necessity of semicolons. This is my example:

```scala
var str = "123.4"
var d = str toDouble
if(d > 10)
    println("Larger than 10")
```

These codes cannot be compiled. Because `if(d > 10) println("Larger than 10")` returns value and compiler thinks this value is a parameter of `toDouble` method. However, `toDouble` doesn't have a parameter. This causes error.

The easiest way to solve this is adding a semicolon at the end of line 2. Just like this:

```
var str = "123.4"
var d = str toDouble;
if(d > 10)
    println("Larger than 10")
```

This confused me and I thought I don't need semicolons at all as I won't put two statements at same line. It makes me uncomfortable that some lines end with semicolon while the others don't. Also, does it makes sense?

Comment: The answer for the question should probably give you some clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656799/when-are-scala-semicolons-required

Comment: From my view, the grammar design is wield, it should not be so confusing, and error-prone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When are Scala Semicolons required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656799/when-are-scala-semicolons-required)

Answer (score 14):

Aggregating possible answers: To write same thing without syntax error you could use:

- Semicolon

  ```
  var d = str toDouble;
  if (d > 10) println("Larger than 10")
  ```
- Dot Syntax

  ```
  var d = str.toDouble
  if (d > 10)  println("Larger than 10")
  ```
- Parenthesis

  ```
  var d = (str toDouble)
  if (d > 10)  println("Larger than 10")
  ```
- Braces

  ```
  var d = {str toDouble}
  if (d > 10)  println("Larger than 10")
  ```
- Empty line separator

  ```
  var d = str toDouble

  if (d > 10)  println("Larger than 10")
  ```

Choose the one which suits your style.
But in normal (non-DSL) code you will usually meet dotted version

A [most] usual use of semicolon is inside simple `for` expressions with several bindings.

```
  for(i <- 1 to 4; j <- 1 until i) println(f"$j < $i")
```

Which by the way could be refactored to semicolonless version too:

```
  for{i <- 1 to 4
      j <- 1 until i} println(f"$j < $i")
```

Comment: You could also ascribe the type at the end of the line to end the expression: `var d = str toDouble : Double`.

Answer (score 6):

Semicolons are sometimes required when using postfix operators. This is part of the reason why postfix operators are a language feature that you'll be warned about if you haven't explicitly enabled them. You could use the `str.toDouble` syntax instead.

Comment: Yes, it works. Since I'm not familiar with coding convention of Scala.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Imm, postfix operators are an added feature. By importing `scala.language.postfixOps` you enable the compiler to acccept postfix syntax, hence this works

```
import scala.language.postfixOps

var str = "123.4"
var d = str toDouble
if(d > 10)
    println("Larger than 10")
```

Comment: Did not work in non-worksheet\non-script code for me

Comment: In repl (sbt console, 2.11.6) if you are entering `:paste` mode it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put a semicolon sometimes, to make compiler understand that value next is not a parameter to the previous one. Like in your case:

```
var str = "123.4"
```

In code above,  string ("123.4") does not takes any paramater so compiler automatically understands that it's end of line and any variable or function next to it is start of new line. But in case:

```
var d = str toDouble
```

As we can pass parameters to **toDouble** method, so compiler will understand that variable next to it is parameter for the same, to avoid these kind of situations we have to make put semicolon and make compiler understand about end of line.